# Conditional formatting based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

My Excel sheet looks like this:

```
+=========+=========+=================================+======================================+
|   MPN   |  BRAND  |              TITLE              |                 URL                  |
+=========+=========+=================================+======================================+
| GB38905 | GRIFFIN | All-Terrain Case for iPhone ... | https://www.example.com/gb38905.html |
+---------+---------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

.. and I need to highlight the *background* of the **row** to green|orange|red based on these conditions (all case insensitive):

- URL AND TITTLE contain MPN -> GREEN
- URL OR TITTLE contain MPN -> ORANGE
- URL OR TITTLE DO NOT contain MPN -> RED

This is my first attempt at using VBA:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub MySub()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim row As Range
  Dim cell As Range

  Set rng = Range("A1: E17361")

  For Each row In rng.Rows
      For Each cell In row.Cells
          MPN = Range("C1").Value
          If InStr(Range("C3").Value, MPN) And InStr(Range("C4").Value, MPN) > 0 Then
              cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
          ElseIf InStr(Range("C3").Value, MPN) Or InStr(Range("C4").Value, MPN) > 0 Then
              cell.Interior.Color = vbOrange
          Else
              cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
          End If
      Next cell
  Next row

End Sub
```

.. and it obviously doesn't work. It turns ALL rows to green.

Comment: `Instr` returns an integer, not a `Boolean`. Replace `InStr(foo, bar) = True` with `InStr(foo, bar) > 0` or just `InStr(foo, bar) And InStr(foo, baz)`.

Comment: @RobertColumbia YES, it does not work. And I can't debug cause I'm using VBA for the first time ever so I'm clueless. I have done enough research and put effort to ask a perfectly valid question now!

Comment: @Comintern Ah thanks, but it now turns everything to green so still missing something.

Comment: Does your question now show your current code?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Compare Text

Sub MySub()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim row As Range
  Dim MPN, u As Boolean, t As Boolean, clr as long

  Set rng = Range("A1:E17361")


  For Each row In rng.Rows

      MPN = row.Cells(1).Value
      u = InStr(row.cells(4).Value, MPN) > 0
      t = instr(row.cells(3).Value, MPN) > 0

      If u And t Then
          clr = vbGreen
      ElseIf u Or t Then
          clr = vbMagenta
      Else
          clr = vbYellow
      End If

      row.Interior.Color = clr

  Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Super! Almost works but for example `TL-PA4016P KIT TP-Link AV500 Powerline Passthrough Starter Kit - TP-Link http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/cat-18_TL-PA4016P-KIT.html` <- this was turned green when obviously it doesn't fulfll the `And` condition.

Comment: My bad, the column numbers were misaligned. Awesome, thanks heaps!

Comment: btw `vbYellow` is not a valid color, thats also my bad code but just for reference.